# Composing the game screen (LibGDX)

Tags: user-interface, screen, libgdx, stage, divide

Seems like I'm  confused with the next stuff:

- Screen
- ApplicationListener
- Game

I was trying hard but still can't undestand the difference of these terms.
What I'm trying to do:
Create a Class which will be extended from Game (implements ApplicationListener or Screen), it will be the area, where all actions happen (player movement, spawning enemies, etc). Then create a class that will be probably implemented the Screen. Score, multipliers and some usefull text will be there.
Then I want to create a stage in another class that includes my classes (thin line with score on high of the screen and the area with the game below. In other words I want to divide the game and text).

Hope you get the idea, so how should I realize the classes with the game, score and a main class which includes them? (Screen, ApplicationListener, Game)
Or there is a way how to do it easier?

Answer (score 3):

The `ApplicationListener` is the entry point of your LibGDX application. LibGDX has several backends to support multiple platforms. All those backends get an `ApplicationListener` which will be one of your self-made classes.

`Game` actually `implements ApplicationListener` which means that you could also supply a `Game` instead of an `ApplicationListener`. But a `Game` has more functionality, since it is a class and not only an interface. It provides you with a basic approach to split your game in several logical parts, which will keep your code more clean. Those parts are called `Screens`. A `Game` will always have one `Screen` which will count as the active one and all the methods from `Game` are actually just being forwarded to the currently active `Screen`.

A `Screen` is one more of your own classes which you implement. It could be a `SplashScreen`, a `LoadingScreen` or a `GameplayScreen`... maybe a `MainMenuScreen` and an `OptionsScreen`. What about a `HighscoresScreen`? You get the idea here. Whenever you want to switch the `Screen` you will use `Game.setScreen()` to do so. This in turn will call `Screen.hide()` on the current `Screen` and `Screen.show()` on the next `Screen`.

Comment: verry detailed answer. +1 for that. But you could also add, that `setScreen()` calls `hide()` on the old screen and `show()` on the new screen. But as i said verry deatiled and easy to understand. As usual (:

Comment: I added it, even though you already wrote it in your answer. Your answer explains everything I didn't. +1 as well!

Answer (score 1):

The `ApplicationListener` Interface gives you all the Methods, which are called by the main game loop:

1. `create()` is called when your App is started for the first time.
2. `dispose()` is called when your App is getting closed.
3. `pause()` is called when a call is incoming or you press the homebutton.
4. `resume()` is called, when you come back to the App, after `pause()` has been called.
5. `resize()` is called on desktop when you resize the window.
6. `render()` is called once every Gameloop (max 60 times per ).

Extending `Game` does more or less the same, but it allready has some deffault implementations. Those deffault implementations call this functions on the current screen. So if you start your App `create()` is called on your `Game` class and this calls `create()` for your current `screen`.

A `Screen` reppresents the things which have to be rendered on `Screen`. Most times there are different `Screen`s for different logics. So for example a `MainMenuScreen` a `GameScreen` and a `OptionsScreen`. Those `Screen`s can be set by calling `setScreen()` in your `Game` class. This automatically calls `hide()` for the current `Screen` and `show()` for the new `Screen`.
I hope this helps you by understanding Libgdx.